# Add property variable to object array php

Tags: php, arrays

How can I add the property to the array object variables?
Let's say I have variable object like this:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => Nuklir
            [id] => 715
            [title] => Testing Article Nuklir
            [alias] => testing-article-nuklir
            [title_alias] => 
            [introtext] => <p><span style="color: #666666; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 19px;" mce_style="color: #666666; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 19px;">Vivamus libero eros, dictum id aliquam in, tristique id sapien. Maecenas rhoncus malesuada aliquet. Morbi vulputate vulputate mauris quis condimentum. Ut ut ligula et mauris accumsan tristique ut nec lacus.</span></p><p><span style="color: #666666; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 19px;" mce_style="color: #666666; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 19px;">Vivamus libero eros, dictum id aliquam in, tristique id sapien. Maecenas rhoncus malesuada aliquet. Morbi vulputate vulputate mauris quis condimentum. Ut ut ligula et mauris accumsan tristique ut nec lacus.</span></p><p><span style="color: #666666; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 19px;" mce_style="color: #666666; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 19px;">Vivamus libero eros, dictum id aliquam in, tristique id sapien. Maecenas rhoncus malesuada aliquet. Morbi vulputate vulputate mauris quis condimentum. Ut ut ligula et mauris accumsan tristique ut nec lacus.</span><br /></p>
            [fulltext] => 
            [sectionid] => 7
            [state] => 1
            [catid] => 25
            [created] => 2012-12-10 07:51:03
            [created_by] => 110
            [created_by_alias] => 
            [modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [modified_by] => 0
            [checked_out] => 0
            [checked_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [publish_up] => 2012-12-10 07:51:03
            [publish_down] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [hits] => 0
            [images] => 
            [urls] => 
            [ordering] => 1
            [metakey] => 
            [metadesc] => 
            [access] => 0
            [slug] => 715:testing-article-nuklir
            [catslug] => 25:nuklir
            [readmore] => 0
            [author] => migrasi
            [usertype] => Super Administrator
            [groups] => Public
            [author_email] => test@yahoo.com
        )

)
```

What I want here, is to add new properties eg. [site_id] => 1 below the [author_email]. Is it possible?

Comment: Object properties are not specifically ordered (though array keys are...) but you have an object inside an array with one index `[0]` so `$yourvar[0]->site_id = 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you have basically (an array with an object at the 0 index)...

```
$array = array(new stdclass);
print_r($array);
```

This gives you

```
 Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

)
```

Now you want to add some property to that object...

```
$array[0]->site_id = 1;
print_r($array);
```

This will give you

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [site_id] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: @MuthuKumaran Please point me to any document that provide information how to set as correct answer. I just see the option "was this post useful to you : yes | no"